# Disabling cache on CakePHP 2.4.4

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

I've read a bunch of Stackoverflow questions with the same goal: disabling cache in the CakePHP framework. However, none of these solutions has worked for me unfortunately.

My core.php now has these values, but the caching of controllers and views is still unbearably long for development:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
$duration = '+1 day';
if (Configure::read('debug') > 0) {
    $duration = '+1 seconds';
}
```

Comment: That's not how it is done in CakePHP. Use the response class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini
and may be in 
/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.5.3/php.ini

comment out the line in this block!
[OPcache]

spent three days on this

Comment: You win the internet.  I could kiss you right on the mouth.

Answer (score 6):

in `app/Config/core.php`

enable `Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);`

worked for me. after this no `models` and `persistent` cache generating.

Answer (score 4):

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeResponse::disableCache

So in your controller:

```
$this->response->disableCache();
```

either globally via beforeRender callback, or specifically per action.

Note that for IE8 comp. regarding this you might need to add an additional header as shown [here](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Controller/MyController.php#L26).

Comment: I've added this to my AppControler.php, but it is still caching.
public function beforeFilter() {
  $this->response->disableCache();
}

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was an issue with MAMP / PHP.
MAMP was set to PHP 5.5.3. After downgrading to version 5.2.17 the caching problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

File: `public_html/app/Config/core.php`

Uncomment below code:
`Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);`

It works!